# How can I take data from MongoDB and display it on a marketplace?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

I'm new to backend and databases. How can I take data from MongoDB and display it on a marketplace?

I have just created a MongoDB cluster for product information and would like to display the product information on my marketplace. I am looking to retrieve data (image and text) from my MongoDB cluster and display different product information and image for each product card.

Here's my current marketplace product card code. Can you advise me on how I can add the backend code to connect the frontend to the database, and show a different product image and information for each product card?

```
function Example(product)
{
  console.log (product)
    product.map (product=>{return product.imagelink})
    var items = [
        {
            src: product.product.media,
        }
    ]

    return (
        <Carousel
          width= '95%'
        >
            {
                items.map( (item, i) => <Item key={i} item={item} /> )
            }
        </Carousel>
    )
}

function Item(props)
{
    return (
        <Link to={{
        pathname: '/app/print',
        state: { id: 123 },
      }}
        >
          <Paper
            square= "true"
            width= '100%'
            elevation= {0}
          >
              <h2>{props.item.name}</h2>
              <p>{props.item.description}</p>
              <img src={props.item.link}></img>
              {/* <Button className="CheckButton">
                  Check it out!
              </Button> */}
          </Paper>
        </Link>
    )
}

const ProductCard = ({ product, ...rest }) => (
  <Card
    sx={{
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'column',
      height: '100%'
    }}
    {...rest}
  >
    <CardContent>
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: 'flex',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          pb: 3
        }}
      >
        <Example 
          product= {product}
        />
        {/* <Avatar
          alt="Product"
          src={product.imageLink[0]}
          variant="square"
        /> */}
      </Box>
      <Typography
        align="center"
        color="textPrimary"
        gutterBottom
        variant="h4"
      >
        {product.title}
      </Typography>
      <Typography
        align="center"
        color="textPrimary"
        variant="body1"
      >
        {product.description}
      </Typography>
    </CardContent>
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} />
    <Divider />
    <a></a>
    <Box sx={{ p: 2 }}>
      
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={2}
        sx={{ justifyContent: 'space-between' }}
      >
        <Grid
          item
          sx={{
            alignItems: 'center',
            display: 'flex'
          }}
        >
          {/* <AccessTimeIcon color="action" /> */}
          <Typography
            color="textSecondary"
            display="inline"
            sx={{ pl: 1 }}
            variant="body2"
          >
             Updated on {moment(product.dateUpdated).format('llll')}
            Price: 20,000USD
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid
          item
          sx={{
            alignItems: 'center',
            display: 'flex'
          }}
        >
          <Button className="CheckButton">
            <AddShoppingCartIcon color="action" />
          </Button>
          <Typography
            color="textSecondary"
            display="inline"
            sx={{ pl: 1 }}
            variant="body2"
          >
            {product.price}
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  </Card>
);

ProductCard.propTypes = {
  product: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default ProductCard;
```

In the code, I'm currently using dummy data that are fixed on the frontend. Can you please advise me on how I can retrieve data (image and text) from my MongoDB cluster and display different product information and image for each product card

Answer (score 0):

For your requirements, you need a simple HTTP server that can be built using Express and there are two options serving images:

- Using Some cloud provider and storing the image's URL in your database, this way you can store and serve high-quality images without too much load on your end. https://fintelics.medium.com/creating-a-s3-uploading-service-with-node-js-and-aws-sdk-1553e129b587
- Or storing the image itself in your database, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/

Moving about how you can connect your frontend and backend, you need to make HTTP calls from your frontend to backend using fetch API or libraries like Axios, which I guess you know about.

Ref: https://expressjs.com/ | https://mongoosejs.com/ | https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-log-a-node-js-api-in-an-express-js-app-with-mongoose-plugins-efe32717b59/